# Ios creating simple camera overlay in Xcode how?

Tags: ios, xcode, camera

As the title says, I need to create a very simple camera overlay while taking photos with `UIImagePickerController`. I want to add very simple `.png` file (like an empty box) over the camera but I can't figure out how to do it.

I've checked most of the tutorials in this webpage but don't understand most of them. It seems very hard to me and adding one simple `.png` file to the camera overlay should be easier than that.

```
(IBAction) getPhoto:(id) sender {
    UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;

    if((UIButton *) sender == choosePhotoBtn) {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    } else {

    }

    label1.text =@"PHOTO ACTION";

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
}
```

Where should I implement my overlay code? What classes should I use and how can I do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a property of `UIImagePickerController` called `cameraOverlayView`. It's an `UIView*`, so you need to create one and put your PNG to the background of it, then assign it to this property of your `picker`.

Ok, here's the code (i didnt test it so)

```
(IBAction) getPhoto:(id) sender 
{
    UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;

    // creating overlayView
    UIView* overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:picker.view.frame];
    // letting png transparency be
    overlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimagename.png"]];
    [overlayView.layer setOpaque:NO];
    overlayView.opaque = NO;

    picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
    picker.cameraOverlayView = overlayView;

    if((UIButton *) sender == choosePhotoBtn) 
    {
         if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
         {
             [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
         } else {
             //do something if the device has no camera or if the camera is disabled in settings (it cannot be assumed that the camera is available/not broken)
         }
    } else {

    }

    label1.text =@"PHOTO ACTION";

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
```

Of course, you can use some custom `UIView*` subclass instead of creating standard `UIView* overlayView`, but everything else will remain the same.

Comment: and how its done I mean where should I implement the camera overlay view codes ?

Comment: Here is your frame = a viewcontroller created by me and named as cameraovarlayview ? and what are those your code to show picker goes there ?

take a look at this example its too complex I only want to show a one simple png in the middle of the screen like the sun the link not  the rest of the buttons.

http://mworldapps.com/custom-camera-overlay-view-for-uiimagepickercontroller-how-to-block-pinch-zoom-2/

Comment: What do you mean? You don't need to create anything else. Most possibly, you'll set it to `picker.view.frame`

Comment: picker.frame how to set it ? by the way thanks for your answers so far.

Comment: a typo. it's `picker.view.frame` indeed. You don't need to create any more classes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17083/discussion-between-bugra-sezer-and-dreamzor)

Comment: This crashed `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Source type must be UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera'
***`