# Is it possible? camera api ios

Tags: ios, camera

I want to implement a feature in app in which when the user takes a picture through the app, what he sees on the screen is:

1. the normal viefinder, showing the image the user will capture
2. an extra layer, not completely transparent probably an alpha of 0.4. this layer consists of an outline of a face. this is so that the user can align his image with the outline.

After this when the user takes the picture all the app does is show just the face(part of the picture inside the outline) with an animated body.
I am not sure if adding that extra layer(point 2) is possible.

also it is not important for the outline to be an outline of a face, could be an outline of a human body instead or of a tree or anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ios creating simple camera overlay in Xcode how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572113/ios-creating-simple-camera-overlay-in-xcode-how)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a little google.  You are looking for an [overlay.](https://www.google.com/search?q=ios%20camera%20api%20overlay)

Comment: I'm sorry for the question, I know its not technical as questions usually should be on stackoverflow but i didnt know overlay was the keyword for my problem, Thank you though :)

Comment: No Problem..My answer was too short, so I ended up adding the google bit.  More snarky then I intended.