# Show layer while taking picture

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I was wondering if its possible to show a layer (UIImageView?) on top of the camera view while taking a picture. I know its easy to implement a layer after the photo is taken but I want to show that layer while taking the picture. Think of it like a frame for your picture.
I've never seen an app that has done this before so I was wondering if it's even possible.

Comment: You are looking for an *overlay*  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527736/is-it-possible-camera-api-ios/

Comment: thanks. Enough information. Post it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you are looking for is an **overlay**

[Here's Apple's sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Listings/OverlayViewController_m.html).