# Which framework to use to make simple animations over a camera view

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, animation

in my Application I like to use the frontcamera to display the user on the iPad/iPhone. This is already working. Now I like to have a simple transparent "HUD" floating over the cameradisplay. It's just a circle which should fill itself, so it is quite a simple animation. Since I am new to iOS Developing I am not sure which framework to use. Unfortunately there is no canvas like in android/html.
Can you please recommend a framework for doing the animations?

I would be very happy for a nice start into my next assignment!

Answer (score 0):

[Ios creating simple camera overlay in Xcode how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572113/ios-creating-simple-camera-overlay-in-xcode-how)

The above question provides an answer which should help you add your own view over the top of the camera feed.

Make this an instance of a custom UIView subclass of your own which has the desired functionality.

UIKit has plenty of functionality for an animation as basic as the one you are describing. Look at setting the corner radius of your `view.layer` object and maybe animating a view from bottom to top using `[UIView animateWithDuration:]`.