# How do I place a sort of guideline mask when the user takes a picture in iOS?

Tags: ios

How do I add to my iOS app some sort of guideline to tell the user something they should take a photo at, like a face?

[image: img1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not Swift, but perhaps it may help you:

[Ios creating simple camera overlay in Xcode how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572113/ios-creating-simple-camera-overlay-in-xcode-how)

As [dreamzor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1280800/dreamzor) says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12572393/1135714), there is a property of `UIImagePickerController` called `cameraOverlayView`. It's an `UIView`, so you need to create one and put your PNG to the background of it, then assign it to this property of your `picker`.