# How to implement this view in image picker controller

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to implement this view for taking and saving images in the app sandbox.
Can someone suggest some opensource libraries?

[image]

Comment: That looks like a custom view made by using AVFoundation framework.

Comment: Teja is right, you will need to use AVFoundation and add a custom overlay to the camera. Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572113/ios-creating-simple-camera-overlay-in-xcode-how